# Application closing unexpectedly c#.net

Tags: c#

I have inherited a large system and I am having a strange issue where I click on a button and the entire application crashes, this is when I include the latest dll in an update. I get no exceptions or Not responding etc and the application just closes completely. I am unsure why this is.

All I need to know is what could be the possible causes of this, is it an un-handled exception and would I need to locate this? The strange thing also is that it is working locally, only when I publish and run on the server.

Any ideas to get me started would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's happening in the button event handler?

Comment: Please specify platform/technology.

Comment: Is there some error logging active for the application? if not, could you add some?

Comment: In a WPF application this hints at an uncaught exception.

Comment: Can you post the code fired when the button is pressed?

Comment: Write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.

Comment: @Alex it is binding data to a control, it is a massive control and the code would swap this post, it is calling a Stored procedure into the dataset and populating the controls. I have done a try catch around the code where it populates the fields and that is not throwing an error

Comment: @SWeko, There is error logging as far as I can see, I have just checked the Event viewer and nothing is relative to this crashing out

Comment: @DanielHilgarth how can I handle uncaught exceptions generically throughout the system, is there any way to catch these globally as I am unsure where it is occurring and being it a huge system I would like to narrow it down.

Comment: @CR41G14: As Hans said above, you need to subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth How would I do this?

Comment: @CR41G14: I don't understand. Are you asking how to handle an event?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Sorry I mean where would I put this handler as the button is adding a control to a page, constructing and then loading the data, the click event is in another control

Comment: @CR41G14: You would put that somewhere at the start of your application, maybe in the main method or the constructor of the main method.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have put this exception handler in the static Main() function where it calls application.Run(), there is no exception being thrown. Any further ideas?

Comment: @CR41G14: Please update the question with the code of your main.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Thanks for all the comments, it was down to a crystal reports exception version. As all exceptions were being caught the program was just bombing out. I put a try catch around the Aplication.Run() and the exception was then Shown in a Message Box.

Comment: @CR41G14: Nice job tracking that down :-)

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to a server you should always include some sort of exception handling in your code. E.g `try catch` which allows you to print the exception message in a message box to clearly know whats going on.

```
try
    {
       //here you will have all the code that takes care of the database connection
    }
catch(Exception e)
    {
         // log error here.. E.g MessageBox.Show(e);
    }
```

This is the standards you should follow when it comes to server connections. This will also prevent your system from crashing.